# Difficulty in understanding proof of Bolzano Weierstrass theorem .

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am studying Bolzano Weierstrass theorem.

It states ' Let $\emptyset\neq S \subseteq R$ and $S$ be bounded and infinite. Then there exists a limit point of $S$ (in $R$).'

I am trying to understand its proof but I am stuck in start of the proof what I don't understand is the following.
To prove the theorem first construct a set $A_s$ = {$x\in R$|$x\ge s $ for finitely many $s\in S$   }. Also clarify what is meant by  term '**finitely many s**'? As I am confused if set S is infinte then how we can choose finite points?

Question 1 . Is $A_s$ finite or infinite ? I am unable to visualize $A_s$ and unable to understand how this set is constructed . So provide some figure to visualize this set.

Question 2 . I have always difficulty understanding "less than or equal to" . I am confused by term 'or' for eg. $x\le 5$ if $x\in R $ it means $x =5$  and x is all points less than 5.
Now if we change the condition to $x \notin N$ then $x \neq5 $. So to prove this theorem we constructed set $A_s$ with condition  $x\ge s$ I want to know when x is equal to s ?

Proof

Step 1 : sup$A_s$ exists.

Since $S$ in bounded , let  $l$  be a lower bound of $S$ . Then $l\le s \ \forall s\in S$.
****Hence $l\gt s$ , for no $s\in S$****. This implies $l\in A_s .$
I want to know how $l$ belongs to $A_s$. It implies set $A_s$ in non empty.

In step 2 : sup $A_s$ is limit point of S

As we know sup$A_s = u_0$ is out limit point interval ($u_0 - \epsilon, u_0 + \epsilon $) contains infinte points of set S.
My second question is.
Is it true  that ($u_0 - \epsilon , a $) contains finite elements of S if $a \in A_s $ and $u_0 - \epsilon \lt a$  ? As (I think) $A_s $ contains only finite points of set S.

Comment: A confusing thing here is that your set should likely be called just $A$ or $A_S$ (to emphasize its dependence on the entire set $S$), rather than $A_s$, since it really does not depend on a particular element $s \in S$. I would suggest re-doing the proof using: $$A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : \mbox{$x\geq s$ for at most finitely many $s \in S$}\}$$

Comment: In my book it is A sub s. And I don't know the reason.

Comment: actually I am quite confused with the term finitely many and at most finitely many . Can you please explain the difference ? Can you suggest any resource to study this particular proof .

Comment: Now for question 1, the definition of $A$ does not suggest whether or not the set $A$ is finite or infinite, but the fact that $S$ is bounded means that there is a finite real number $b$ such that $s\geq b$ for all $s \in S$, and so all of the (infinite number of) real numbers that are less than or equal to $b$ are also in the set $A$.

Comment: The phrase: "for finitely many $s \in S$" was intended to mean the same as "for at most finitely many $s \in S$" (meaning that there are not an infinite number of such $s$, there are only finitely many) and so I was just using a wording that I personally find to be more clear.

Comment: Still I am unable to visualize the set please help me with a example. Please suggest some resource to study this whole proof

Comment: Consider the example set $S = \{0\} \cup  \{1\} \cup (2,3)$, where $(2,3) = \{x\in \mathbb{R}:2<x<3\}$.   Now you can find out what the set $A$ is for that particular $S$.   To start you can ask: Is $-1 \in A$?  Is $0.5 \in A$? Is $2.5\in A$? and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134604/discussion-between-nikhil-pathak-and-michael).

Comment: Okay so there are only certain type of S which we can take like example you gave ? Here S is infinite as well as a subset of S i.e ${0,1}$ is finite here. So elements of A is [0,2) . Am I right?

Comment: The set $S$ can be any infinite and bounded set, I gave one example here that I think is a good illustrative example. Note that indeed we have $-1 \in A$ because there are no elements of $S$ less than or equal to $-1$, and the empty set is a finite set. Also, $2 \in A$ but $2.1 \notin A$.  In fact $A = (-\infty, 2]$ and $\sup A = 2$.  For any bounded and infinite set $S$, the corresponding set $A$ will be an interval of the type $(-\infty, a]$ or $(-\infty, a)$.